# Possible to use both multiple view engines and multiple view folders in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on a project that currently relies on Jade templates and uses the following setup:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

I'm building a 'V2' version of the site and will be using client-side HTML rather than Jade. I setup a basic workaround to avoid the current Jade structure by doing the following in my route handler:

```
function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../assets/v2', 'index.html'));
};
```

The problem is that I now also need to send `req.user` details along with rendering the page, and obviously `res.sendFile()` does not allow this.
Ideally I would like to do something like this in my route handler:

```
function(req, res) {
  res.render(path.join(__dirname, '../assets/v2', 'index.html'), {user: req.user});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You would be writing a lot of redundant code if you want to serve dynamic html without any templating engine. Express doesn't offer any functionality to do this by itself, and it shouldn't.

What you can do otherwise is build a REST API, use MVC on client side (`angular.js` is pretty good) and serve data.

For eg:

```
GET /user-data

{
    user: some_user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your `index.html` file and make it a `index.jade` template that puts the `user` info wherever you want.

The browser will receive it as an HTML file, not a jade template.